# Regular expression for js object

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```
{{ renderBlock("sometext1",{
    id:1555267
}) }}
{{ renderBlock("sometext2",{
    id:15553
}) }}
{{ renderBlock("sometext3",{
    content:"somecontent"
}) }}
```

So, i need extract arguments from function renderBlock
I can parse first argument, but i cant parse second argument - js object

The regexp `/{{ renderBlock\("(.*)",{(.|\n)[^)}]*/` doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about how your string can change, but this works for the example given:

```
renderBlock\("(.+)",((.|\n)+?)\)
```

Group 1 is the first argument, Group 2 is the second argument.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/yTUUPo/2)

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is between curly braces, maybe this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/2Em722/1) is what you are looking for:

`{{ renderBlock\("(.*)",({(?:.|\n)+?})`

This will result in 2 capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

I tweak your regex just a bit. Try this

```
'{{ renderBlock("sometext3",{content:"somecontent"}) }}'.match(/{{ renderBlock\("(.*)"(,\{[^)]*\})\)*.*/)
```

The regex

```
/{{ renderBlock\("(.*)"(,\{[^)]*\})\)*.*/
```